# SVG getBoundingClientRect() + "transform: rotate()" is bugged in Chrome in a very specific way

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, chromium, css-transforms

getBoundingClientRect() works fine on all SVG elements except in the circumstance when an element is rotated in Chrome.

Below I have drawn 2 lines, the one on the left is diagonal and the right line starts vertical, as represented by the black lines. The green box is a visual representation of the getBoundingClientRect(). I then apply the same transform rotate to both lines at the same time and then update the bounding box visual.

As you can see from the following, the left bounding box does not represent the actual bounds, however, the right one does.

The problem is I need the true client bounds of the line in whatever orientation it is. This works fine in Firefox. Does anyone know of another way to get or calculate the bounds when a line, specifically, has a `transform rotate`?

I have posted a copy of this here: [getBoundingClientRect() + "transform: rotate()" is bugged in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237400/getboundingclientrect-transform-rotate-is-bugged-in-chrome). To help people with a similar problem, but then decided I'd actually ask the community.

Chrome: v100.0.4896.75

This bug has now been reported to the cromium bugs board here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1314959

**UPDATE:** I've added the same 2 static lines with a direct `transform` attribute with a rotation of 40deg, and 2 div's representing the 'getBoundingClientRect'. The left box is clearly not showing the smallest rectangle which contains the entire element.

**UPDATE 2** Included a `BBox` Visual in blue. `getBBox()` simply calculates the bounds of a child relative to the SVG element itself, prior to any rotation transforms. `getBoundingClientRect` does calculate the transform correctly, but is using the `BBox`, which has it's own issues here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377665

```js
let l = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(d => document.getElementById(`line${d}`)),
  vis = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(d => document.createElement(`div${d}`)),
  bboxvis = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(d => document.createElement(`div${d}`)),
  r = 0;

vis.map((element) => {
  document.body.appendChild(element)
  element.style.position = "absolute"
  element.style.border = "1px solid green"
  element.style.background = `#0FF0002e`
})
bboxvis.map((element) => {
  document.body.appendChild(element)
  element.style.position = "absolute"
  element.style.border = "1px solid blue"
  element.style.background = `#0000FF2e`
})

let updateBounds = (element, displayElement, bboxvisEl) => { 
  let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    svgBounds = element.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect(),
    bbox = element.getBBox(),
    d = document.documentElement;
  displayElement.style.top = rect.y+d.scrollTop+"px"
  displayElement.style.left = rect.x+d.scrollLeft+"px"
  displayElement.style.width = rect.width+"px"
  displayElement.style.height = rect.height+"px"
  bboxvisEl.style.top = bbox.y+svgBounds.y+d.scrollTop + "px"
  bboxvisEl.style.left = bbox.x+svgBounds.x+d.scrollLeft +"px"
  bboxvisEl.style.width = bbox.width+"px"
  bboxvisEl.style.height = bbox.height+"px"
}

[3,4,5].forEach(i => {
    updateBounds(l[i], vis[i], bboxvis[i]);
  bboxvis[i].style.transform = `rotate(40deg)`;
})

setInterval(() => { 
  [0,1,2].forEach(i => {
    l[i].setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${r} 80 80)`);
    bboxvis[i].style.transform = `rotate(${r}deg)`;
    updateBounds(l[i], vis[i], bboxvis[i]);
  })
  r++; 
  if(r===360) r=0;
}, 20)
```

```css
.container {
  width:140px;
  height:140px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">
  <line x1="40" y1="40" x2="120" y2="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="40" y1="40" x2="120" y2="120" id="line1" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">
  <line x1="80" y1="30" x2="80" y2="130" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="80" y1="30" x2="80" y2="130" id="line2" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">
  <line x1="60" y1="30" x2="100" y2="130" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="60" y1="30" x2="100" y2="130" id="line3" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
<br/>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">
  <line x1="40" y1="40" x2="120" y2="120" id="line4" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(40 80 80)"></line>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">
  <line x1="80" y1="30" x2="80" y2="130" id="line5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(40 80 80)"></line>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">
  <line x1="60" y1="30" x2="100" y2="130" id="line6" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(40 80 80)"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: The [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) returns **the smallest rectangle which contains the entire element**, that mean that a sloping line rectangle has a width greater than its `stroke-width`, so this may be a bug in Firefox not in Chrome.

Comment: @syduki You can see from the left box (in chrome and edge chromium) it ISN'T giving the smallest rectangle containing the entire element, regardless of stroke. If you run this in Firefox you can clearly see the bounding box is correct and both sides match as they should. The black line is just showing the initial position and not being used for the calculations.

Comment: You should look at initial figures, in Chrome we have `line1=80x80` and `line2=0x100` while in Firefox `line1=81.4667x81.4667` and `line2=2.01669x100`. Why Firefox is returning different results when rotating that rectangle is unclear.

Comment: @syduki Yeah, why that's happening is unclear as well. I've placed 2 static versions of the same lines with a fixed rotate transform on both. Chrome is still reporting the client bounds incorrectly. I've also reported this to Chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1314966

This was an issue with standard element transforms, at least until about November 2021 as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237400/getboundingclientrect-transform-rotate-is-bugged-in-chrome